# how to migrate from sql 2000 to sql 2008 via restore?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, migrate

I'm running this code:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB_2009May11] 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\DB Copy\MyDB_2009May11.bak' 
WITH  
MOVE N'Archive_Data' 
    TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.mdf',  
MOVE N'Data' 
    TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.mdf',  
MOVE N'Log' 
    TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  
STATS = 10
GO
```

I'm getting this error:

Msg 3176, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
File 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.mdf' is claimed by 'Archive_Data'(3) and 'Data'(1). The WITH MOVE clause can be used to relocate one or more files.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

How the crap do I migrate from sql server 2000 to 2008 when all I have is the backup file?

:)  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a select * from sysaltfiles and look at the correct filenames and then change the names in the move to part accordingly

This will give you the names of all the filegroups currently

```
select filename from master..sysaltfiles
where name = 'MyDB_2009May11'
```

if you don't have the databse scripted yet then do this first. make sure the folders exists, you might also want to change the filesizes

```
    CREATE DATABASE [MyDB_2009May11] ON (NAME = N'Data',
    FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.mdf'
     , SIZE = 12, FILEGROWTH = 10%),
     (NAME = N'Archive_Data',
    FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.ndf'
     , SIZE = 12, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
    LOG ON (NAME = N'Log', 
FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.ldf'
     , SIZE = 21, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
     COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Now the restore should be this, notice the ndf extension for the archive filegroup

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB_2009May11] 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\DB Copy\MyDB_2009May11.bak' 
WITH  
MOVE N'Archive_Data' 
    TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.mdf',  
MOVE N'Data' 
    TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.ndf',  
MOVE N'Log' 
    TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  
STATS = 10
GO
```

Comment: Dude.  That was an amazing answer.  I'll try this in the morning when I get back to the office.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to move Archive_Data and Data to the same file - change the file name and you should be fine :)

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I think this is the simplest answer. +1 for you.

Comment: This was actually the solution for me.  I went through the GUI to create my restore script, but it had some file names the same.  So I changed them and it worked. +1

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well, and just a little add on I had to use the `REPLACE` clause because the database I was restoring to was different than in the database backup:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB_2009May11]  
FROM  DISK = N'C:\DB Copy\MyDB_2009May11.bak'  
WITH   
MOVE N'Archive_Data'  
    TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.mdf',   
MOVE N'Data'  
    TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.ndf',   
MOVE N'Log'  
    TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQL2008\MSSQL\DATA\MyDB_2009May11.ldf',   
**REPLACE**,
NOUNLOAD,   
STATS = 10 
GO
```